# Is there a formula for winning $21$?

Tags: probability, combinatorial-game-theory

There is a game I play; it's called $21$, the rules are as follows.

1. Each turn a player says either the next $1,2,3$ or $3$ from the player previous.
2. The games starts at $0$ and ends at $21$.

I've figured out how to win with $100%$ certainly when $2$ players. It's going second. Most people only find that $20$ and $16$ are the numbers there after because if say those they win why? Because $16$ can always be forced into $20$. $16$ can be played into $17$ $18$ $19$ all of which can go to $20$ and you can go the other way $12$ can force $16$ if you say it and you can keep going down to $4$ which you can force if you go $2$nd.

The formula for this is $(n-5)-4)-4)-4)\ldots\, n $ is $21$ and you all the numbers you take as in the product of this equation are winning numbers so that's $2$ players now this is question for you.

How can I maximize my odds of winning with $3,4,5$ players?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I have a couple of questions about your game. First, you wrote "Each turn a player says either the next 1,2,3 or $\color{red}{3}$ from the player previous", but shouldn't the $\color{red}{3}$ be $\color{red}{4}$ instead? Also, you don't explicitly state how the game is won, but from your later description, it appears to be when the opposing player is forced to go to $21$. Please edit your question to clarify these points.

Comment: In 3,4,5 player game, by winning do you mean not losing? Like is your aim to not be the person to count 21?And are you assuming that all other players have an equal probability to say anyone number?

Comment: Is this on-topic?

Comment: @EtackSxchange Yes. Games like this ("subtraction games") are well-studied in Combinatorial Game Theory, and multiplayer games are studied in Game Theory as well.

Comment: John-as for your question yes I did make that mistake sorry as for winning the game you need every other player to say 21 if they say 21 or a number higher then they lose and you can only say 3 numbers not 4 i dont know why I did that

jinansh-your goal in 3,4,5 player games your goal is to make all other players say 21 so there out and you win